# Elasticsearch custom plugin: Add extra query parameter before search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm new with Elasticsearch, so don't know how to start properly with the following task.

I have an index with documents that contain 2 types of fields:

- address: the string including city and street;
- houses: the list of houses' numbers (integers).

In usual case I could search this documents by followin query:

**(1)**

```
GET /_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should": [
        {"match": {"address": "Gotham Fourteenth street"}},
        {"match": {"houses": 33}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to match such records by single string, like:

**(2)**

```
GET /_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should": [
        {"match": {"address": "Gotham Fourteenth street 33"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or even:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=Gotham+Fourteenth+street+33'
```

i.e. convert the query **(2)** to **(1)**, that is cut the house number '33'  from 'address' and put it as 'houses' match-parameter to the same query before search performed.

I think I could create a plugin in Java that would extract house number from 'address' (parsing is not a problem) and add an extra parameter 'houses' with this value.

Thus my problem is:

1. how in my plugin I can programmatically add an extra match-parameter 'houses' to my query before search performed?
2. how to cut the trailing house-number token from 'address' parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've developed a plugin for ElasticSearch 2.4.2 and added a REST-action class (derived from `BaseRestHandler`) with the following `handleRequest()` method:

```
@Override
protected void handleRequest(RestRequest request, RestChannel channel, final Client client) throws Exception {
    // Get the address parameter
    String address = request.param("address");

    // ... Code that parses address and extracts house number ...
    int house = ...

    // Now send both parameters as query to search engine
    SearchResponse sr = client
        .prepareSearch("myindex")
        .setTypes("mytype")
        // Query all shards, DFS==calculate global words' frequencies
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        // Address string without (cutted) house number   
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("address", address))
        // And extracted house number as second filtering parameter
        .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("houses", house))
        // Starting position of the first returning hit
        .setFrom(0)
        // Max number of hits
        .setSize(10)
        // Explain hit score 
        .setExplain(true)
        .get();

        // Convert the search response to rest response and send it
        BytesRestResponse sr_rest = search2restResponse(sr);
        channel.sendResponse(sr_rest);
    }
}
```

The method `search2restResponse()` mentioned above converts SearchResponse to REST-response and looks as following:

```
private BytesRestResponse search2restResponse(SearchResponse sr) {
    SearchHit[] searchHits = sr.getHits().getHits();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < searchHits.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            builder.append(",");
        }
        builder.append(searchHits[i].getSourceAsString());
    }
    builder.append("]");
    String res_json = builder.toString();
    return new BytesRestResponse(RestStatus.OK, res_json);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=address:"Gotham Fourteenth street"`

`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=address:"Gotham Fourteenth street" AND (houses=13)`

Also checkout [wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Comment: The #1 query of course finds the needed records, but it will find all the records with all houses. In my case I should find only record with house #33. And more complex: house number should be in 'address' parameter as a whole string.


I'll explain: the customer's frontend supports only single string as address. And in other hand I have no opportunity to preprocess this string to split it into 2 parameters before sending to elastic. So I should do this preprocessing entirely in elasticsearch.